# Accessing document inside <iframe> using JS. "contentWindow.document" and "contentDocument" doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, greasemonkey

What I'm trying to do is to hide some elements(divs that contain ads) from video player using JavaScript (**not jQuery**). I use Greasemonkey.

Video player is embedded into the site by < iframe > :

```
<iframe src="//www.mp4upload.com/embed-f9ntae302eec.html" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" width="765" height="431" frameborder="0">
```

My script as of right now:

```js
function remove_iframe_ads(){
  var video_player_window = document.getElementById("player-block");
  if(video_player_window == null) return;

  var iframes = video_player_window.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
  if(iframes == null || iframes.length == 0) return;

  console.log(iframes[0]);        // for debugging

  var iframe_document = iframes[0].contentDocument || iframes[0].contentWindow.document;
  console.log(iframe_document);
};

setInterval(remove_iframe_ads, 1000);
```

Through debugging I found out that `console.log(iframe_document);` doesn't get to run.
Actually `var iframe_document` isn't even created (code execution stops as `var iframe_document`).

It seems that I can't access the "document" inside an `iframes[0]`.
**Is `var iframe_document = iframes[0].contentDocument || iframes[0].contentWindow.document;` simply wrong or is the iframe being somewhat "protected" against local changes?**

I followed [this doc](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp) to write "crossbrowser" solution.

---

Have been looking through Google and StackOverflow, but I didn't find any answers on "How to get element inside an iframe in JS" apart from what I used here.

---

Output of   `console.log(iframes[0]);` (unfolded):

```
iframe
​
accessKey: ""
​
accessKeyLabel: ""
​
align: ""
​
allowFullscreen: true
​
allowPaymentRequest: false
​
assignedSlot: null
​
attributes: NamedNodeMap(6) [ src="//www.mp4upload.com/embed-f9ntae302eec.html", scrolling="no", allowfullscreen="", … ]
​
baseURI: "https://shinden.pl/episode/45069-gate-jieitai-kanochi-nite-kaku-tatakaeri-2/view/137211#column-one-inner"
​
childElementCount: 0
​
childNodes: NodeList []
​
children: HTMLCollection { length: 0 }
​
classList: DOMTokenList []
​
className: ""
​
clientHeight: 431
​
clientLeft: 0
​
clientTop: 0
​
clientWidth: 765
​
contentEditable: "inherit"
​
contextMenu: null
​
dataset: DOMStringMap(0)
​
dir: ""
​
draggable: false
​
firstChild: null
​
firstElementChild: null
​
frameBorder: "0"
​
height: "431"
​
hidden: false
​
id: ""
​
innerHTML: ""
​
innerText: ""
​
isConnected: true
​
isContentEditable: false
​
lang: ""
​
lastChild: null
​
lastElementChild: null
​
localName: "iframe"
​
longDesc: ""
​
marginHeight: ""
​
marginWidth: ""
​
name: ""
​
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
​
nextElementSibling: <form action="http://player.shinden.eu" method="post" target="_blank" style="text-align:right; margin: 10px 20px">​
nextSibling: #text "
"
​
nodeName: "IFRAME"
​
nodeType: 1
​
nodeValue: null
​
offsetHeight: 431
​
offsetLeft: 5
​
offsetParent: <div class="player-online box" style="">
​
offsetTop: 10
​
offsetWidth: 765
​
onabort: null
​
onanimationcancel: null
​
onanimationend: null
​
onanimationiteration: null
​
onanimationstart: null
​
onauxclick: null
​
onblur: null
​
oncanplay: null
​
oncanplaythrough: null
​
onchange: null
​
onclick: null
​
onclose: null
​
oncontextmenu: null
​
oncopy: null
​
oncuechange: null
​
oncut: null
​
ondblclick: null
​
ondrag: null
​
ondragend: null
​
ondragenter: null
​
ondragexit: null
​
ondragleave: null
​
ondragover: null
​
ondragstart: null
​
ondrop: null
​
ondurationchange: null
​
onemptied: null
​
onended: null
​
onerror: null
​
onfocus: null
​
onfullscreenchange: null
​
onfullscreenerror: null
​
ongotpointercapture: null
​
oninput: null
​
oninvalid: null
​
onkeydown: null
​
onkeypress: null
​
onkeyup: null
​
onload: null
​
onloadeddata: null
​
onloadedmetadata: null
​
onloadend: null
​
onloadstart: null
​
onlostpointercapture: null
​
onmousedown: null
​
onmouseenter: null
​
onmouseleave: null
​
onmousemove: null
​
onmouseout: null
​
onmouseover: null
​
onmouseup: null
​
onmozfullscreenchange: null
​
onmozfullscreenerror: null
​
onpaste: null
​
onpause: null
​
onplay: null
​
onplaying: null
​
onpointercancel: null
​
onpointerdown: null
​
onpointerenter: null
​
onpointerleave: null
​
onpointermove: null
​
onpointerout: null
​
onpointerover: null
​
onpointerup: null
​
onprogress: null
​
onratechange: null
​
onreset: null
​
onresize: null
​
onscroll: null
​
onseeked: null
​
onseeking: null
​
onselect: null
​
onselectstart: null
​
onshow: null
​
onstalled: null
​
onsubmit: null
​
onsuspend: null
​
ontimeupdate: null
​
ontoggle: null
​
ontransitioncancel: null
​
ontransitionend: null
​
ontransitionrun: null
​
ontransitionstart: null
​
onvolumechange: null
​
onwaiting: null
​
onwebkitanimationend: null
​
onwebkitanimationiteration: null
​
onwebkitanimationstart: null
​
onwebkittransitionend: null
​
onwheel: null
​
outerHTML: "<iframe src=\"//www.mp4upload.com/embed-f9ntae302eec.html\" scrolling=\"no\" allowfullscreen=\"\" width=\"765\" height=\"431\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>"
​
ownerDocument: HTMLDocument https://shinden.pl/episode/45069-gate-jieitai-kanochi-nite-kaku-tatakaeri-2/view/137211#column-one-inner
​
parentElement: <div id="player-block" class="player-container">​
parentNode: <div id="player-block" class="player-container">
​
prefix: null
​
previousElementSibling: null
​
previousSibling: #text "
"
​
referrerPolicy: ""
​
sandbox: DOMTokenList []
​
scrollHeight: 431
​
scrollLeft: 0
​
scrollLeftMax: 0
​
scrollTop: 0
​
scrollTopMax: 0
​
scrollWidth: 765
​
scrolling: "no"
​
shadowRoot: null
​
slot: ""
​
spellcheck: false
​
src: "https://www.mp4upload.com/embed-f9ntae302eec.html"
​
srcdoc: ""
​
style: CSS2Properties(0)
​
tabIndex: 0
​
tagName: "IFRAME"
​
textContent: ""
​
title: ""
​
width: "765"
​
<prototype>: HTMLIFrameElementPrototype { getSVGDocument: getSVGDocument(), src: Getter & Setter, srcdoc: Getter & Setter, … }
```

Comment: Specifically, [*this answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4333824/2341603) which states to use `iframe.contentWindow.document` instead of `iframe.contentDocument`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge According to [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp) either of those should work. Any reason why I should discard `iframe.contentDocument`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iframe on a different origin, hence fiddling with the `<iframe>` element on the *parent* page won't permit you to view anything inside the child.

While it would be possible to set up a userscript to run on both the parent page and the child page, and then communicate between the iframe and its parent window with `postMessage`, you probably *only* need to run the script inside the iframe. Change your metadata block to include the child page instead (`mp4upload.com`), and then you can remove the ads from there.

As a side note, polling with `setInterval` to hide elements is a bit inelegant - if you want to hide certain elements, you might be able to just insert a CSS stylesheet instead. For example, the ad-removal script could be something like the following:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).textContent = `
.ad-container {
  display: none;
}
`;
```

where you replace `.ad-container` with the selector(s) of the ad containers, of course. Then there won't be need for any other Javascript, the stylesheet can take care of it all.

Comment: As far as I know, if I need to use `.parentNode` I can't do this with just `.css` (?). Every other "ad-blocking" feature, I inserted into css file. I'm planning to make some sort of "event listener" to check whether created elements are to be deleted.  
//
So if I change metadata block, will I be able to access `iframe` from the same scope as I access default `document` block?